# Hibernate - Group two entities

Tags: java, hibernate

I have this code:

```
Map<OrderProduct, Product> temp = 

session.createQuery("FROM OrderProduct " +
                    "WHERE orderId = '" + orderId + "'", OrderProduct.class)
        .getResultList()
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                                k -> k,
                                v -> session.createQuery("FROM Product " +                                                       
                                                         "WHERE id = '" + v.getProductId() + "'", Product.class)                                                                                                            
                                             .getSingleResult()));
```

Here I take all `order products` of an specific order(`orderId`).

After make a stream and collect it as `Map`.

On key put `order products` and for value make another query to get `product`(product info).

Now I do 2 queries for every `order product`. There is a way to make all of this with just a single query?

Something like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM order_products OP, products P
WHERE OP.product_id = P.id;
```

But I don't know how to use in hibernate.

Here are entities:

@Entity

```
@Table(name = "order_products")
public class OrderProduct{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "order_id")
    private Integer orderId;

    @Column(name = "product_id")
    private Integer productId;

    @Column(name = "quantity")
    private Integer quantity;

    //getters setters

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "products")
public class Product{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    Integer id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    String name;

    //getters setters

}
```

Here is a short example of how db look:

```
OrderProduct:
id-----order_id-----product_id-----quantity
1------1------------1--------------2
2------1------------2--------------1
3------2------------1--------------1

Product:
id-----name
1------productOne
2------productTwo
```

Comment: Can you provide the entity classes ? what relation Product and OrderProduct have with each other ?

Comment: @AnishB. I updated my question. This relation `OrderProduct.productId` is foreign key of  `Product.id`, but this relation is declared in mysql.

Comment: is it many to one or one to one ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with those terms. One `OrderProduct` can have only one `Product`. But one `Product` can have multiple `OrderProduct`.

Comment: Then you have a one to many relation.

Comment: @AnishB. I added a short example of how db look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For many to one relation :

Change your entity to this :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "products")
public class Product{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    Integer id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    String name;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "product", cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
    private List<OrderProduct> orderProducts = new ArrayList<OrderProduct>();

    //getters setters

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "order_products")
public class OrderProduct{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name = "product_id")
    private Product product;

    @Column(name = "quantity")
    private Integer quantity;

    //getters setters

}
```

Now the code :

```
int orderId = 1; // put any id
OrderProduct orderProduct = session.get(OrderProduct.class, orderId);
System.out.println(orderProduct.getProduct().getId());
```

Hope this helps you. :)

Comment: Really thanks. Short question. `mappedBy` serving for what?

Comment: So, in my case: mappedBy = "product" ?

Comment: Yes !! accidently wrote something else. I have updated that.

Comment: you have to mention the name of the entity(class name).